# How to list avaliable resources per node in MPI?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing

I have an access to MPI cluster. It is a pure, clean lan cluster, no SLURM or anething except OpenMP, mpicc, mpirun installed. I have sudo rights. Accessible and configured MPI nodes are all listed in  `/etc/hosts`. I can compile and run MPI programms, yet how to get information on MPI cluster abilities: totall cores avaliable, processors info, total memory, currently running tasks?

Generaly I search for analog of [`sinfo`](http://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html) and  [`squeue`](http://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) that would work in MPI environment?

Comment: First would be to just look at the cluster's documentation. If you don't know where it is, or if it doesn't exist, ask your system administrators and/or support team... Or maybe the question is a generic one? In which case, please be more specific on what you want to get, and what tools you want to / can use.

Comment: Can you be more clear on your question? As you define it, I can not see where is the problem. For example, why you can not use `sinfo` or `squeue` (I can assume, but it will be just an assumption) ? You can also check the Portable Hardware Locality (`hwloc`) (if you haven't check it already), but since I can not understand your problem, I can not be sure about the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

total cores avaliable:
total memory:
You can try to use Portable Hardware Locality [hwloc](https://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) to see the hardware topology and get info about total cores and total memory. 
Additionally you can get information about CPU using `lscpu` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

currently running tasks:
You can use the monitoring software `nmon` from IMB (its free)
The option `-t` of `nmon` reports the top running process (like `top` command). You can use nmon online or offline mode.

The following example is from [IMB developerWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/)

`nmon -fT -s 30 -c 120`

Is getting one "snapshot" every 30 seconds until it gets 120 snapshots. Then you can examine the output.

If you run it without -f you will see the results live